# I need to use SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: java, android, mysql, xampp

Im trying to connect my application to a Xampp mysql server that i have in my pc. The question is if dont know if i need to use SQLiteOpenHelper yes or yes? Or i can do all in the main activity? Here goes my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         if (conectarMySql()){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WORKS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }else{
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONT WORK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

        }
    });


}


public boolean conectarMySql() {
    String xServidor = "10.0.2.2";
    String xPuerto = "3306";
    String xUsuario = "user1";
    String xPass = "pass1";
    String notwork = "not work";
    String xBase = "penia";
    String estado = "";
    boolean estadoConexion = false;
    Connection conexionMySql = null;

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String urlMySQL;
    urlMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://" + xServidor + ":" + xPuerto + "/";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

        conexionMySql = DriverManager.getConnection(urlMySQL + xBase, xUsuario, xPass);

        if (!conexionMySql.isClosed()){
            Log.e(notwork,"CONEXION BIEN");
            estadoConexion = true;
            estado = "bien conexion";
        }

    }catch (Exception EX){
        Log.e(notwork,"Con");
    }


    Log.e(notwork,estado);
    return estadoConexion;

}
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You use SQLiteOpenHelper *only* when you create a SQLite database in the app. If you want to connect to database outside the app then you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks so much, i will not forget that advice, take it for sure. But the code still dont work, it's properly done? Maybe I am missing something? Or i need to use 100% a web service to comunicate between XAMPP SQL and my Android Application?